# WCF RIA Services Domain Service not found when debugging with Windows Azure cloud project

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, wcf-ria-services

I am trying to debug a Windows Azure Cloud project locally with Visual Studio 2012 running the Windows Azure SDK 1.7 on a Windows 8 PC with IIS 8 Express. The cloud project includes a Web Role running an ASP.NET MVC 3.0 web project that includes WCF RIA Services that in turn links to a Silverlight project hosted on that web site. When I run the web site directly and do not try to debug the Azure cloud project I am able to access the web site and the Silverlight application and the RIA Services are accessible with absolutely no issues. If however I debug the Azure Cloud project the emulators start up and the web site comes up. I am able to then access the Silverlight application but when it tries to make a request back to the WCF RIA Services Domain Service I receive an error from the IIS Server stating that the domain service is not available. I then try to go directly against the WCF RIA Service endpoint to see if it will come up outside the Silverlight application and again I receive a 404 Not Found response when going to the *.svc endpoint.

I have gone through various searches to try and resolve the issue and I have used Fiddler to ensure the network requests are not having any issues. I have not been able to identify any problems. I also tried turning on WCF tracing to see if any errors comes up, but the trace files are not even updated when I debug through the Azure Cloud project.

After repeatedly getting this behavior I have attempted a complete re-install of Visual Studio 2012 and the Azure 1.7 SDK, but I still get the same behavior. Does anyone have a suggestion of what the issue may be or how I might try and track down the issue, since the WCF tracing is not offering me any additional information?

Answer (score 0):

Strange. Could you try [this sample project](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=1BCE1D5766DF232B!3311&authkey=!AMYu537-QcYNqTg), which is quickly created with VS2012 on W8 using IIS8 Express, .NET 4.0, MVC3 hosting Domain Service and Silverlight consuming that domain service. Everything works just fine.

If that project runs at your environment fine - then it might be some missconfiguration of your web.config/global.asax file. If that project also fails in your environment - then it might be something very messy with the environment.

Comment: I brought your project down locally and I was able to run it successfully with no issues. I looked through the web.config settings and I don't see any issues. The DomainServiceModule is the exact same on both sides, with the same version being referenced. I confirmed the same references are labeled as Copy Local -> True between both projects as well. I confirmed the Properties windows are lining up in terms of settings as well. Do you know of any additional tracing I can put in place to see what the issue is?

Comment: Do you have [this hotfix](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB971842) installed? It is related to WCF metadata, not sure whether it is relevant in your case, but in anyway your service lives behind a load balancer in Azure (and Azure Emulator)

Comment: I am running Windows 8, so this hotfix would not apply in my case. I actually tried doing a complete reinstall down to the OS and still get the same behavior, so I can only assume I have some issue in the project.

Comment: Can you isolate a sample project where this error is steadily reproduced, but there is no business logic/objects that subject to intellectual property rights. If you can do so, then you might be able to share the project for further investigation.